# Difference between 'Core data without iCloud' and iCloud core data?

Tags: core-data, icloud, icloud-drive

I had worked with Core data (using NSPersistentContainer, NSManaged object) to handle my local data storage in my previous application. Now i am looking to work with syncing data across the devices using iCloud core data storage. Is that the same procedure for creating core data and do sync additionally on it! or the way of creating core data is different with respect to the iCloud core data.?
Kindly suggest me the best way to handle iCloud with core data. Thanks in advance..

Comment: I'll be flagging this as a duplicate in a moment. I believe you have a typo in your title - shouldn't *without iCloud* be *with iCloud*? If so, then there's already an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I'm mistaken. There's no *accepted* answer, but there are two answers that may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45445759/core-data-with-icloud-vs-icloud-core-data/45464362#45464362